# gedmo/doctrine-extensions asking for a token when installing via composer

Tags: github, composer-php, doctrine-extensions

Is anyone else having an issue  gedmo/doctrine-extensions installing via composer?

The repository is public so I am not sure why it's saying it is a private repo

`Cloning failed using an ssh key for authentication, enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+computername+2015-09-04+1040
to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "/location/.composer/auth.json" for future use by Composer.
Token (hidden):`

Answer (score 6):

In short: you are hitting the API rate limit, because you don't auth against it.

The Github API has a very low rate limit, so if you install lots of packages it will at some point fail and ask you for your login/password.

If you prefer to not provide your GitHub credentials to Composer, you can manually create a token using the following procedure:

- Create an OAuth token on GitHub (https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens).
- Add it to the configuration running `composer config -g github-oauth.github.com <oauthtoken>`

Now Composer should install/update without asking for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

git install your system

close cmd (command promt)

Comment: Can you explain what it does and why this should work ?